# Policy to audit resource group, resources and tag

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I am looking to configure policy to audit resource groups that contains resources, whether have the particular tag or not. If the resource group does not have any resources, then there is no need to audit. My requirement is only to perform audit for tags, if the resource group contains resources. Is it a possible scenario for creating policy?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is fair to say that your requirement is to audit for resources and not the resource groups, you can achieve this by using the built-in policy definition "Require a tag on resources" and set it to "audit" instead of "deny".

EDIT:

Considering your clarification, you can perform the reverse check - meaning a check on resources, inspecting their resource groups:

```
    "parameters": {
        "tagName": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "displayName": "Tag Name",
                "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
            }
        }
    },
    "policyRule": {
        "if": {
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "field": "type",
                    "notEquals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
                },
                {
                    "not": {
                        "field": "[resourceGroup().tags[parameters('tagName')]]",
                        "exists": "false"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "then": {
            "effect": "audit"
        }
    }
```

Here we are checking that we are not looking at a resource group directly. Then, we check if the parent resource group does not have the specified tag (notExists).

/MMT

Comment: No. I want to audit the resource group for tag only if it contains the resources. I don't want to audit my empty resource groups. Hope it clears.

Comment: The approach I suggested should audit resources, thus not audit empty resource groups - did you want only resource groups, not resources, to be audited?